# Find $a,b,c$ if ${(1+3+5+.....a)}+{(1+3+5+....b)}={(1+3+5+.....c)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, diophantine-equations, arithmetic-progressions

If $${(1+3+5+.....a)}+{(1+3+5+....b)}={(1+3+5+.....c)}$$
and $$(a+b+c)=21, a\gt6$$

We have to find $a,b,c$

**My attempt**

I use a little fact that the sum of first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$

From that i get $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Which means that the solutions are pythagorean triples, and found no such soultion.

While if i try to do this by hand, $$a=7,b=5,c=9$$ satisfies the question but not the pythaoarean equation that i set up above

Why is this so?

Comment: It is not true that $1+3+5+\cdots +a=a^2$.

Comment: You have the constraint $a + b + c = 21, a > 6$. To narrow things down, assume that $a$ is the least possible value, i.e., $a = 7$. Then $b+c = 14$. This is a good pointer I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=2n-1$ so $$1^2+3^2+...+a^2=n^2=\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)^2.$$
Id est, $$(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2=(c+1)^2$$ or
$$a^2+b^2+2a+2b+2=(22-a-b)^2$$ or
$$ab-23(a+b)=-241$$ or
$$(a-23)(b-23)=288.$$
Also we have $a\geq7$, $b+c\leq14$, $c>b$ and $c>a$.

Can you end it now?